# viewPager.setCurrentItem() doesn't work in onActivityResult

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have implemented [FragmentStatePagerSupport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). I have 142 pages. I have also an activity that is MyListActivity and has ListView. When I click ListView item, it returns a page number. I want to use this page number for viewPager current page.  `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` doesn't work in onActivityResult.

Here is how I call startActivityForResult:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(icindekiler, 0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the listView of MyListActivity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ListViewContent selectedItem = (ListViewContent) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            int pageNo = book.getSpine().getResourceIndex(selectedItem.getResource().getHref());
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("PageNo", pageNo); // pageNo: 0 or 1 or 2 or ... or 142
            setResult(0, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult method in FragmentPageStateSupport activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == 0) {
        if (data.hasExtra("PageNo")) {
            pageNo = data.getExtras().getInt("PageNo");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "pageNo is " + pageNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNo);
        }
    }
}
```

For example `pageNo` is 11, Toast says "pageNo is 11" but `viewPager` doesn't change. When I use debugging in Android Studio, application runs Looper.java. I try `viewPager.setCurrentItem(11)` on different method (for example button click), this time it is working.

Comment: You could try storing the result inside `onActivityResult` and performing the `setCurrentItem` inside of `onResume`.

Comment: @cwbowron Thank you so much. It works.